# Пунктуация при указании процентов

Tags: пунктуация, или

На работе регулярно приходится писать такие фразы "Расходы исполнены в сумме 500 руб. или на 10 % от плана". Я машинально обособляю запятыми часть "или на 10%", другие коллеги пишут без запятых. Правил, к сожалению, не нашла, но в мозгу засело, что обособление необходимо. Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3):

Интуиция вас не подводит. Здесь запятая нужна, поскольку в качестве уточнения приводится иное исчисление той же суммы ("или на 10%" = "что составляет 10%"). Без запятой подобное выражение означало бы выбор одной из независимых альтернатив, например, предложение спланировать расходы одним из двух способов (на выбор: в сумме такой-то или в виде процента от того-то).

Answer (score 1):

**Перед "или" запятая нужна**, так как приводится другая интерпретация той же суммы, а не выбор между двумя вариантами.

Однако **обособление всей фразы** про проценты здесь **использовать не стоит** - "Расходы исполнены в сумме 500 руб., или на 10 % от плана". (перед "от плана" запятая не нужна)